# Connect to an URI in postgres

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm guessing this is a pretty basic question, but I can't figure out why:

```
import psycopg2
psycopg2.connect("postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres")
```

Is giving the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: missing "=" after
"postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres" in connection info string
```

Any idea? According to [the docs about connection strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) I believe it should work, however it only does like this:

```
psycopg2.connect("host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres")
```

I'm using the latest psycopg2 version on Python2.7.3 on Ubuntu12.04

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The connection string passed to `psycopg2.connect` is not parsed by `psycopg2`: it is passed verbatim to `libpq`. [Support for connection URIs was added in PostgreSQL 9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING).

Answer (score 85):

I would use the `urlparse` module to parse the url and then use the result in the connection method. This way it's possible to overcome the psycop2 problem.

```
from urlparse import urlparse # for python 3+ use: from urllib.parse import urlparse
result = urlparse("postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres")
username = result.username
password = result.password
database = result.path[1:]
hostname = result.hostname
port = result.port
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    database = database,
    user = username,
    password = password,
    host = hostname,
    port = port
)
```

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but I was hoping to find something more general that will accept any `RFC 3986` URI postgres would accept.

Comment: I guess this is some kind of psycop2 limitation you'll have to live with

Comment: I finally found out what the problem was. Whether URI connection strings are supported are not depends on your `PostgresQL` version (and NOT on your `psycopg2` version). I am running PostgresQL version 9.1 which does not support them.

Comment: This suggestion by @Daan solved my problem, thanks! If upgrading to a newer version of postgres is an option, do it. Also, note that you will have to remove (e.g. `pip uninstall psycopg2`) and then reinstall (e.g. `pip install psycopg2`) after upgrading postgres itself.

Comment: I don't think it depends on **PostgreSQL** version, but the libpq version that psycopg2 is using.

Comment: The urlparse module is renamed to urllib.parse in Python 3.

Comment: This is a bad answer. Any password containing `#` would be registered as having an URL fragment, and hence it'd put everything after `#` as a fragment. `postgresql://username:VeRyCoMpl#xPasSwOrD@super-postgres.com:5432/dbname` would be `ParseResult(scheme='postgresql', netloc='username:VeRyCoMpl', path='', params='', query='', fragment='xPasSwOrD@super-postgres.com:5432/dbname')`

Answer (score 7):

To update on this, Psycopg3 does actually include a way to parse a database connection URI.

Example:

```py
import psycopg # must be psycopg 3

pg_uri = "postgres://jeff:hunter2@example.com/db"
conn_dict =  psycopg.conninfo.conninfo_to_dict(pg_uri)

with psycopg.connect(**conn_dict) as conn:
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for this. It's not just ORM, it consists of two distinct components **Core** and **ORM**, and it can be used completely [without using ORM layer](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/features.html).

SQLAlchemy provides such functionality [out of the box](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#postgresql) by `create_engine` function. Moreover, via URI you can specify **DBAPI** driver or many various [postgresql settings](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2).

Some examples:

```py
# default
engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:pass@localhost/mydatabase")
# psycopg2
engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@localhost/mydatabase")
# pg8000
engine = create_engine("postgresql+pg8000://user:pass@localhost/mydatabase")
# psycopg3 (available only in SQLAlchemy 2.0, which is currently in beta)
engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg://user:pass@localhost/test")
```

And here is a fully working example:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# set connection URI here ↓
engine = sa.create_engine("postgresql://user:password@db_host/db_name")
ddl_script = sa.DDL("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo_table (
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        data TEXT NOT NULL
    );
""")

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # do DDL and insert data in a transaction
    conn.execute(ddl_script)
    conn.exec_driver_sql("INSERT INTO demo_table (data) VALUES (%s)",
                         [("test1",), ("test2",)])

    conn.execute(sa.text("INSERT INTO demo_table (data) VALUES (:data)"),
                 [{"data": "test3"}, {"data": "test4"}])

with engine.connect() as conn:
    cur = conn.exec_driver_sql("SELECT * FROM demo_table LIMIT 2")
    for name in cur.fetchall():
        print(name)

# you also can obtain raw DBAPI connection
rconn = engine.raw_connection()
```

**SQLAlchemy** provides many other benefits:

- You can easily switch **DBAPI** implementations just by changing URI (*psycopg2*, *psycopg2cffi*, [etc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#dialect-postgresql)), or maybe even databases.
- It implements connection [pooling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#connection-pool-configuration) out of the box (both [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html) and [psycopg3](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/pool.html) has connection pooling, but API is different)
- [asyncio support](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html) via `create_async_engine` (*psycopg3* also [supports asyncio](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/async.html)).